# Tooltip of Image in Datagrid not Showing

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip

I have a datagrid column (Badges) with images of badges in each cell. For each image in a cell, I want to hover over the badge image in the cell and a tool tip should appear indicating a number. I am trying to do this in XAML but it is not working. Here is what I tried to do:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Stars" Width="140" CellStyle="{StaticResource NoFocusColumStyle}" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Badges}" Height="23">
                                <Image.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip Content="{Binding Badgenum}" />
                                </Image.ToolTip>
                            </Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Basically I want to hover over the badges images in the Column and it should show Badgenum. But the tool tip is not working. It's not showing any error though. What am i missing?

Comment: your question is unclear because it lacks [MCVE]

Comment: Is the Badgenum property defined in the same class as Badges? What's the type of the property?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Badgenum is a string, you don't need to create a tooltip object yourself, just bind to the tooltip property of the image ...

```
<Image Source="{Binding Badges}" Height="23" ToolTip="{Binding Badgenum}" />
```